# Python and SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, database

Hello I need help with Python and SQL.

I have 2 tables:

users_table:

`userid | name |`

tasks_table:

`userid | name | date`

What I need it's get users ids from 1st table:

`SELECT userid FROM users_table`

And use those userids to make SELECT from second table:

`SELECT count(date) from tasks_table WHERE userid=xxx`

How can I do it with python? I'm tried to use loop but it didn't work for some reason maybe I did something wrong.

I'll be grateful for any help.
Thanks!

Comment: one option: `select count(date) from tasks_table where userid in (select userid from users_table)`.

Comment: I don't understand why you talk about python here. Python sure?

Comment: **How can I do it with python**, what "SQL" are you using, are you using `SQLite`, `mySQL` or `postgreSQL`? Of course the **specific** process is not the same. Most popular RDMS's  have a python connector library, meaning you can execute SQL statements from there. We'll need to know what you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT U.USER_ID,COUNT(T.DATE)AS CNT
FROM USERS_TABLE AS U
LEFT JOIN TASKS_TABLE AS T ON U.USER_ID=T.USER_ID
GROUP BY U.USER_ID
```